Как по имени аннотированного атрибута класса получить класс и создать объект
from typing import Annotated

class Attr:
    title: str
    def __init__(self, title: str) -> None:
        self.title = title
    
class Entity:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        for annotation in self.__annotations__:
            # как здесь по имени аннотации получить класс и создать объект?

class Ent1(Entity):
    a_1: Annotated[Attr, 'atr1']
    a_2: Annotated[Attr, 'atr2']

class Ent2(Entity):
    a2_1: Annotated[Ent1, 'atr2_1']

Собственно в тексте скрипта указан вопрос, как в этом месте из аннотированных атрибутов класса создать атрибуты объекта на основании указаного в аннотации класса?

Так self.__annotations__ - это словарь, так вы перебираете только его ключи. Перебирайте сразу пары ключ-значение и там всё будет вроде нужное: for annotation in self.__annotations__.items():
